# Changing content about routing whitout ng-view

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-routing

I have the following html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- ... -->
</head>
<body>
  <section id="section1" ng-include="'section1.html'"></section>
  <section id="section2" ng-include="'section2.html'"></section>
  <section id="main_section" ng-view></section>
</body>
</html>
```

As we can see, I have 3 sections: `section1`, `section2` and `main_section`.
`main_section`is the main section (obviously) and it has `ng_view`attribute, so, when an user enter an url like `http://example.com/#!/main/any` the `main_section` shows the main content. Now, I would like to show new content into `section1`when an user click on a link like `http://example.com/#!/two/other` but I would not to change`main_section` content.

**EDIT: routing**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'module/foo.html',
                controller: 'FooController',
                controllerAs: 'foo'
            }).when('/main/:bar_id', {
                templateUrl: 'module/foo.html',
                controller: 'FooController',
                controllerAs: 'foo'
            }).otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }]);
```

Comment: What does your routing look like?

Comment: @cDima, I have added routing code

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console ?

Comment: No, no errors. I would like to add the new behavior

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that angular routing out of the box does not support nested views; 
You have two options: either use [ngSwitch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) or the state paradigm of [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which supports nested views and hierarchies.

Comment: Thank you, I will try ```ngSwitch``` and I will return.